# HTTP adapter is not working while accessing web service

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

While invoking the adapter in studio it's working

```
{
   "isSuccessful": true,
   "responseHeaders": {
      "Accept-Ranges": "none",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Alternate-Protocol": "80:quic,p=0",
      "Cache-Control": "public, max-age=86400",
      "Content-Type": "application\/json; charset=UTF-8",
      "Date": "Wed, 05 Aug 2015 09:17:20 GMT",
      "Expires": "Thu, 06 Aug 2015 09:17:20 GMT",
      "Server": "mafe",
      "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
      "Vary": "Accept-Language,Accept-Encoding",
      "X-Frame-Options": "SAMEORIGIN",
      "X-XSS-Protection": "1; mode=block"
   },
   "responseTime": 174,
   "results": [
      {
         "address_components": [
            {
               "long_name": "4250",
               "short_name": "4250",
               "types": [
                  "street_number"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name": "South Miami Boulevard",
               "short_name": "S Miami Blvd",
               "types": [
                  "route"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name": "Durham",
               "short_name": "Durham",
               "types": [
                  "locality",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name": "Triangle",
               "short_name": "Triangle",
               "types": [
                  "administrative_area_level_3",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name": "Durham County",
               "short_name": "Durham County",
               "types": [
                  "administrative_area_level_2",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name": "North Carolina",
               "short_name": "NC",
               "types": [
                  "administrative_area_level_1",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name": "United States",
               "short_name": "US",
               "types": [
                  "country",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name": "27703",
               "short_name": "27703",
               "types": [
                  "postal_code"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name": "9138",
               "short_name": "9138",
               "types": [
                  "postal_code_suffix"
               ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address": "4250 South Miami Boulevard, Durham, NC 27703, USA",
         "geometry": {
            "bounds": {
               "northeast": {
                  "lat": 35.9026873,
                  "lng": -78.8516022
               },
               "southwest": {
                  "lat": 35.9026836,
                  "lng": -78.85162009999999
               }
            },
            "location": {
               "lat": 35.9026836,
               "lng": -78.85162009999999
            },
            "location_type": "RANGE_INTERPOLATED",
            "viewport": {
               "northeast": {
                  "lat": 35.9040344302915,
                  "lng": -78.8502621697085
               },
               "southwest": {
                  "lat": 35.9013364697085,
                  "lng": -78.8529601302915
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id": "EjE0MjUwIFNvdXRoIE1pYW1pIEJvdWxldmFyZCwgRHVyaGFtLCBOQyAyNzcwMywgVVNB",
         "types": [
            "street_address"
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status": "OK",
   "statusCode": 200,
   "statusReason": "OK",
   "totalTime": 181
}
```

But it's not working when invoked from the app in the device.

This is adapter **.js file:**

```
function getLatLang(pAddress){
var input = {
            method : 'get',
            returnedContentType : 'json',
            path : 'maps/api/geocode/json',
            parameters : {
                'address' : pAddress,
                'sensor' : 'false' 
            }
        };

        return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);

}
```

This is adapter **.xml file:**

```
<connectivity>
        <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
            <protocol>http</protocol>
            <domain>maps.googleapis.com</domain>
            <port>80</port> 
            <connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>30000</connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>
            <socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>30000</socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>
            <maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode>50</maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode>
            <!-- Following properties used by adapter's key manager for choosing specific certificate from key store  
            <sslCertificateAlias></sslCertificateAlias> 
            <sslCertificatePassword></sslCertificatePassword>
            -->     
        </connectionPolicy>
    </connectivity>
```

This is main.js file:

```
function getLatLang(){
                        //alert("Hi");
                        var gmap = document.getElementById("gmap").value;
                        var invocationData = {
                            adapter : "Go2needsHTTP",
                            procedure : "getLatLang",
                            parameters : [gmap]
                        };
                        //alert("Hi");
                        var options = 
                        {
                            onSuccess : procedureSuccess,
                            onFailure : procedureFailure,
                        };
                        WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, options);
                    }
```

Comment: What's failing? What's not working? What's the error you're getting? Add the error from LogCat when running in the device. Add the log from Chrome DevTools when previewing the app from the MobileFirst Console.

Comment: It's not giving anything in the console..

Comment: Are you sure you are even call this JS function from somewhere? Provide your project so that it could be debugged. Upload it somewhere, like Dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide not your HTML nor how you're calling this function (not the function itself), so if you say that when running the app itself nothing happens this means you're not actually invoking your JavaScript, meaning you have an error somewhere - likely a typo.

W/out fuller code, there is nothing else to say.